# Como chamar web service em teste com MONKEY

Tags: android, web-service, testes

Estou utilizando o MONKEY para fazer teste de stress, porem minha aplicação possui várias chamadas à *webservices* em diversas `activitys`.

O problema é que o monkey nunca chega nas activitys que são abertas após as chamadas dos web services.
Aparentemente o monkey fecha a `activity` antes de abri, porque já percebi que ele chega a efetuar a chamada ao web service.

Será que existe algum comando ou alguma forma de solucionar esse problema?